# How do I work around Old packages that no longer exists in cabal repository?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-snap-framework

For example, I want to build the [snap-pastie](https://github.com/Palmik/snap-pastie) project. But the required package snap-extension-mongodb is not available in the cabal repository.

The same for `snap-extension-*` packages.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to [download and install the package yourself](https://github.com/ozataman/snap-extension-mongodb) (`cabal install` from within the git checkout directory should do it).

However, the code isn't guaranteed to work at all; when that repository was last committed to, Snap was at [version 0.4.2](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-0.4.2); it's now at [0.7](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-0.7). You might have to install old versions of all the Snap packages (`cabal install foo==version`) or, better, try and port the code to the newest version.

By the way, I don't think that package was ever on Hackage; deprecated packages can be hidden from the main list by request, but I don't think they're ever fully deleted, and [the package page](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-extension-mongodb) is a 404.

[snaplet-mongoDB](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snaplet-mongoDB) might help if you decide to port the code to the newest Snap, although it doesn't seem to build right now; you'd have to contact the author.

Answer (score 0):

I like the old snap API much more than the new one with snaplet.

There is a good way to play with the old one, it is [virthualenv](https://github.com/Paczesiowa/virthualenv).

You still have to install the lost packages manually.